# Fitting child molecule concentration in parent molecule exponential decay

Tags: modeling, exponential-distribution

I am new to CrossValidated so hope this question is appropriate... apologies if not.

I am studying the stability of a molecule 'B' and have data on the recorded level at different time points. Molecule B actually increases over time due to the fact that its parent molecule, AB, is decaying releasing it (and A): AB -> A + B

If I were measuring AB I believe it would decay along the following [model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life#Formulas_for_half-life_in_exponential_decay):

$$
N(t) = N_0 e^{-\lambda t}
$$

Where $N_0$ is the start concentration of AB, $\lambda=\ln(2)/t_{1/2}$ and $t$ is time. For example when $N_0=1000$ and $t_{1/2}=2$ we get as below, which when log transformed these form a nice straight line on which real data can easily be fit, see left hand images [in this Google spreadsheet](https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_GB&hl=en_GB&key=0ApdtrT02Tv8sdGpRQmROZFhIOE1vMU1xQ1hGODllNkE&single=true&gid=0&output=html)

However, because I am measuring B, and the parent start concentration is unknown (probably much bigger than B), I am getting a graph like (top-right graph in link), which is a mirror of the decay curve of AB, starting at the start concentration of B (known, and in this example 100) and increasing by the decay of AB: ($N_0 - N(t)$) at each $t$.

However, log transforming this does not produce a straight line, because the concentration is not halving or doubling, but increasing by an amount to do with the unknown start concentration of AB, producing the not very useful graph (bottom-right graph in link).

Therefore, I am finding it hard to fit a line to my data. I have tried converting concentration of B into something that looks like concentration of AB which can then be converted easily into a straight line by log transforming, but had no luck as I don't know $N_0$ for AB.

I am hoping I've missed something and there is a nice way transform my data to a straight line, or model it some other way. Any help and ideas would be very much appreciated!

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that $[B]$ behaves like $N_\infty-N_\infty e^{-\lambda t}$, and the log of this is nothing really interesting. You should subtract this from the asymptotic value to get exponential function again and restore linear look on the log-y plot.

Easy to say, but how to get this $N_\infty$? One way is to wait some time (rule of thumb say $>3/\lambda$, but obviously the more the better) and collect some points then and average them (they will be very close to $N_\infty$).

The better idea is not to plot any lines at all and just use non-linear fitting procedure (such as `nls` in R) to fit $N_\infty\left(1-e^{-\lambda (t-t_0)}\right)$ to the data and just get all those parameters nicely approximated with CIs.

Comment: With this data I am not able to estimate [B] at t=infinity, as (1) data already collected and (2) the halflives are too long even if redid experiment. I will give nls() in R a go, I was just hoping there was a way to get data as a straight line as it is *just* the mirror of a curve that does transform. Thanks a lot.